# Spring Reactive - problem with fromObject() method in BodyInserters class

Tags: java, spring, reactive

I tried following the [documentation tutorial](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/html/web-reactive.html), but I have some issues with depracated method. Specially in this line

```
.then(item-> ServerResponse.ok().contentType(APPLICATION_JSON).body(fromObject(item)))
```

The error is : Target type of a lambda conversion must be an interface.

Below is whole code. Thanks for your help

```
package com.learnreactivespring.learnreactivespring.handler;
import com.learnreactivespring.learnreactivespring.document.Item;
import com.learnreactivespring.learnreactivespring.repository.ItemReactiveRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.ServerRequest;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.ServerResponse;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

import static org.springframework.http.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON;
import static org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyInserters.fromObject;


@Component
public class ItemsHandler {

    @Autowired
    ItemReactiveRepository itemReactiveRepository;


    public Mono<ServerResponse> getAllItems(ServerRequest serverRequest) {
        return ServerResponse.ok()
                .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON)
                .body(itemReactiveRepository.findAll(), Item.class);
    }

    public Mono<ServerResponse> getOneItem(ServerRequest request) {
    String itemId = request.pathVariable("id");
    Mono<ServerResponse> notFound = ServerResponse.notFound().build();
    Mono<Item> itemMono = this.itemReactiveRepository.findById(itemId);
    return itemMono
            .then(item -> ServerResponse.ok().contentType(APPLICATION_JSON).body(fromObject(item)))
            .otherwiseIfEmpty(notFound);
}

}
```